# make a spinning spiral in processing?

Tags: java, processing

So I am a beginner in Java and recently got interested in basic Applets using Processing. I am trying to make a spinning spiral like this: 
[image]

I have the code for a basic spiral here:

```
    import processing.core.*;

public class prac2 extends PApplet{
    double i=0;float r=0;int flag=0;
    int num=1;
    public void setup(){
        frameRate(100);
        strokeWeight(7);
        size(1920,1080);
    }
    public void draw(){

        float x;
        float y;
        x=(float)(r*Math.cos(i)+960);
        y=(float)(r*Math.sin(i)+500);
        println(i);
        point(x,y);
        i=i+(Math.PI)/(180);
        r=r+(40f/360f);

    }
}
```

but I have no idea of how to make it spin like in the image.. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense.

Basically, to create an animation, you need to do three things:

- Create some variables that hold the state of your scene.
- Use those variables to draw your scene each frame.
- Change those variables over time to make the scene change.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on animation in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).

You're actually pretty much already doing that with your current code, but you're hitting a snag because you're actually talking about two different types of animation that sort of compete with each other.

What I mean by this is, look at your example animation: the spiral is rotating, but note that it's not actually growing. It's the same spiral every time, just rotated. Compare that to your spiral, which is continuously growing every frame.

So, your first step is to decide exactly what you want your animation to do: is it a growing spiral, or a spinning spiral, or both?

If you want your spiral to spin, then you're going to have to clear out old frames by calling the `background()` function as the first line in your `draw()` function. That means you'll have to redraw your whole spiral again! But you'll draw it at a rotated angle. If you change that angle over time, then the spiral will spin.

You could also draw your spiral once, to a buffer using the `createGraphics()` function. Then you could just draw the buffer to the screen each time instead of redrawing the whole spiral. Just rotate the buffer to rotate the spiral.

If you want it to both spin and grow, then you'd want to combine all of the above and draw a growing spiral to the buffer, and then draw the buffer at a rotated angle each frame.